Minecraft: How to change the F3 key binding?
F3 is the one of the most important key aspect in Minecraft too see coordinate and much more feature.
My F3 is working but the F3 button isn't too responsive so I need to click harder to use it. I'm using laptop so changing the keyboard is not the answer, are there any tricks or software to change F3 key binding?

This question is similar to: Change F3 Control in Minecraft? | How to show coordinates in Minecraft PC without F3 button on my Gaming keyboard. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
